# SFDX Translation - Override

Tags: salesforcedx, translation, scratch-org, translation-workbench

Following Error occurs when trying to pull(`sfdx force:source:pull`) custom translation override from a scratch org.
Steps to replicate:

1. Navigate to "Override" under "Translation Workbench" in the setup menu.
2. Select a "package", custom field as a "component" and any custom field as the "object"
3. Add a translation
4. From the terminal run `sfdx force:source:pull`

Following error occurs:

sfdx force:source:pull
ERROR:  Cannot retrieve translation for object:XXXXX__c.
sfdx force:source:pull ended with exit code 1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to the following bug: it seems SFDX & translations are currently not very good friends...

You can click "this issue affects me" to accelerate its correction by Salesforce

-> https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ATThQAO

Meanwhile, I suggest you edit your translations directly on force-app local files ( folders translation, objectTranslations )

Next problem will be that force:source:convert seems to ignore some translations metadatas ... but at least your translations won't be lost

Answer (score 2):

I found out one workaround to bypass this issue.
There are two additional steps:

1. Retrieve unpackaged source defined in a `package.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -r ./mdapipkg -u <username> -k ./package.xml
```

2. Convert the metadata back to SFDX format:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir mdapi_project --outputdir tmp_convert
```

After that all object translations (including imported recently) will be available at `tmp_convert\main\default\objectTranslations` location.